# Can we refer to the concrete type (whatever they may be) in interface definition?

Tags: c#

I have to add a `Diff` feature on certain types of objects. I want to come up with an interface which will define objects that are capable of comparing themselves with others of the same types. Let's call it `IDiffable`.

```
interface IDiffable
{
 DiffDetails CompareWith(object other); 
}
```

Now the problem is, in the `CompareWith` method users can pass in any type including the ones that implement IDiffable and the ones that don't. So let's restrict them to the ones that implement IDiffable.

```
interface IDiffable
{
 DiffDetails CompareWith(IDiffable other); 
}
```

Now the one last piece of the puzzle that is left is, users can still pass in the objects of different types than the one call is being made to. How do I restrict that?

Here is an example of what I want to prevent.

```
internal class TypeA : IDiffable
{
 internal DiffDetails CompareWith(IDiffable obj) 
 {
   // compare here
 }
}

internal class TypeB : IDiffable
{
 internal DiffDetails CompareWith(IDiffable obj) 
 {
   // compare here
 }
}
```

I want to avoid the following

```
var a = new TypeA();
var b = new TypeB();
var diff = a.CompareWith(b); // incorrect usage, how to avoid this?
```

I want to allow only the following

```
var a = new TypeA();
var b = new TypeB();
var another_a = new TypeA();
var diff = a.CompareWith(another_a); // Correct usage
```

Comment: What you're looking for is described by Eric Lippert in [Curiouser and Curiouser](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser/)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using generics.

```
interface IDiffable<T>
{
    string Diff(IDiffable<T> obj);
}

class DiffA : IDiffable<DiffA>
{
    public string Diff(IDiffable<DiffA> obj)
    {
        return "Diffable A";
    }
}

class DiffB : IDiffable<DiffB>
{
    public string Diff(IDiffable<DiffB> obj)
    {
        return "Diffable B";
    }
}
```

Its a little messy as you have to state your type twice in the class definition. It also can quickly become unwieldy when you start subtyping or doing more complex restrictions with generics.

However the above code achieves what you wanted.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = new DiffA();
    var b = new DiffB();
    a.Diff(a); // Runs fine
    a.Diff(b); // Compiler error
}
```